# ADF Dynamic Parameters - Error : Failed to validate the signature because the content is tampered

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have a scenario where the same kind of flow is applicable for multiple scenarios. Hence, instead of creating linked services / datasets for every scenario, I am trying to have a generic linked service/dataset so that they can be reused by passing different parameters.

I have a Blob linked service where I parameterized the storage account name. Tested the linked service with a parameter and it is working fine. Now, I create a dataset with this linked service and provide a parameter for the storage account name in the dataset. When I try to test the dataset and provide the same input parameter, I get the below error :

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidCredential,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
Message=**Failed to validate the signature because the content is tampered**, 
the expect context is '{\"DefaultEndpointsProtocol\":\"https\",\"AccountName\":\"xxxx\"}' 
and the runtime context is '{\"DefaultEndpointsProtocol\":\"https\",\"AccountName\":\"@body('Generic Passthrough CopyComposeRuntimeVariables')?.GenericBlobDatasetxxxx.DatasetStorageAccountName\"}'.,Source=diawp,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Generic Passthrough Copy",
    "details": []
}
```

Any pointers to solve the above issue would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The customized dynamic content of the linked server only works at the first time. When you create a dataset with this linked service, it means that the linked server will be published again, then the dynamic content will be overwritten by the default content.

You can check the changes in linked service settings on Portal:

[image]